# Invalid IPv6 URL while running commands using AWS CLI

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

configured AWS Cli on Linux system.
While running any command like "aws ec2 describe-instances" it is showing error "**Invalid IPv6 URL**"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ran into the same error. 
Running this command fixed the error for me:

export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1

You might also try specifying the region when running any command:

aws s3 ls --region us-east-1

Hope this helps!

or run `aws configure` and enter valid region for default region name

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue due to region being wrongly typed. When you run `aws configure` during initial setup, if you try to delete a mistaken entry, it will end up having invalid characters in the region name.

Hopefully, running `aws configure` again will resolve your issue.